# HTTP Live Streaming. "Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up."

Tags: ios, ios6, http-live-streaming, buffering

With new iOS 6 i start getting strange behavior of MPAVController. My app receives video via HTTP Live Streaming from the server. Now i often see messages like this:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

and video get stalled quite often. Moreover, sometimes there is a big QuickTime logo appears instead of video playing.

Haven't found any official info about these issues, so I'm kindly asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran in similar problem recently, erasing EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT helped fix that. There is currently no EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE in my m3u8 playlist, and everything works.